# Создание сайта в IIS из PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, iis

Мне необходимо создать программно новый сайт в IIS.
Для этого использую команду:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ( @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-noexit -executionpolicy Unrestricted New-WebSite -Name \"TestSite\" -Port 80 -HostHeader \"TestSite\" -PhysicalPath " + "\"" + strPath + @"\MyFolderTest\""" );
```

Не работает. При попытке выполнения сообщает об отсутствии терминатора:

> The string is missing the terminator: ".
>
> - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx    ception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Вывел свою команду в текстовый файл, выполнил, всё работает. А вот программно не хочет, хотя теперь это явно одна и та же строка. 
Пробовал экспериментировать с executionpolicy, но вряд ли это из-за разрешения на скрипты... Я его вообще по сути на всякий пожарный ставлю.

В общем, что в этой команде не так? Можно ли как-то вывести то, что пытался выполнить PowerShell, чтобы я мог сравнить строки?

Comment: Напишите вспомогательную программу, которая где-нибудь сохраняет `Environment.CommandLine` - и попробуйте запустить её вместо powershell. А дальше ищите различия.

Comment: что и зачем вы тут `@"\MyFolderTest\"""` экранируете?

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали как правильно

```
string.Format(" -noexit -executionpolicy Unrestricted New-WebSite -Name 'TestSite' -Port 80 -HostHeader 'TestSite' -PhysicalPath '{0}\\MyFolderTest'", strPath);
```